# How to refresh activity without losing all data?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imagebutton

I want to delete an object by clicking in some ImageButton. When i do that the item only disapears when i perform another action. I made my research and it was possible to change that by refreshing the activity. The problem is that when i do that, all the other items also disapear from my list. I tought about adding the objects to a Table by SQLite and then retrieving them again. Is there an easier approach?

Thank you.

*EDIT*

[image]

When i click on a cross of kiwi to remove it

if i have this :

```
 public void removeProduct(View v) {

    Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();

    Product p1 = (Product) adapter.getItem(position);
    productsGridView.remove(p1);
 }
```

it will remove but only if i click on other part of the app, so will not be immediatelly.

I'm looking for a way to do it immediatelly. I was thinking about this

```
public void removeProduct(View v) {

    Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();

    Product p1 = (Product) adapter.getItem(position);
    productsGridView.remove(p1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

but then instead of morango and banana as a result i get 0 products in the list...

Comment: Delete an object from what? A list? A database? Maybe adding some code to your question would help clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you can call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter and that will refresh the listview adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refresh the adapter instead of restarting the Activity

```
public void removeProduct(View v) {

    Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();

    Product p1 = (Product) adapter.getItem(position);
    productsGridView.remove(p1);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed need to refresh the activity, there might be a tricky way to work around. Tricky way means the way i do might not really suitable for this scenario. Have you try static property? The static property will not be released when the finish() is fired in an activity. When the activity rebuild you could load the data from static property. Here is my testing application.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> list;

    private Button btn;
    private int counter = 0;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (list == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                }
                list.add(counter++);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, counter + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (counter == 2) {
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        if (list == null)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "List is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            textView.setText("The list size is " + list.size() + "\nThe counter is " + counter);
    }
}
```

The XML layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this could help. Indeed the solution post by F43nd1r should be a good solution, refresh the view only.

Comment: i realized that i don't need to refresh the activity, only the view, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh the view instead of the whole activity. This way you can keep the data in your current activity instance.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the activity is not necessary.
You should remove your item from the list and notify the adapter with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position).